# Tool in the gettext suite to unify source strings with fuzzy match?

Tags: localization, internationalization, gettext

Is there any way to leverage the tools in the gettext suite to do something like fuzzy match the source strings within one PO file to find strings which are almost identical? This would seem like a useful quality check to improve the sources. Example:

```
#: my_file
msgid "Sorry, something went wrong"
msgstr ""

#: some_other_file
msgid "Sorry, something went wrong."
msgstr ""

#: yet_another_file
msgid "Sorry, something is wrong"
msgstr ""
```

These strings are virtually identical and the source code could possibly be changed to use the same message in each instance. This would reduce the l10n work and make the UI more coherent. It would seem to me that the fuzzy match algorithm in `msgmerge` should already be pretty well suited to identify these instances. Yet I could not find an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do any kind of folding without human supervision.
Most translation tools have that feature, but a human should validate such folding.
You can't even do it for perfectly identical strings because of the context.

Why:

- buttons ("commands") often get translated differently than labels and titles ("descriptions)")

  Example: "Print" is translated to French as "Imprimer" (buttons) or "Impression" (titles)
- gender, number, case, will change the translation.

  Example: translating a "New" button into Spanish can give you "Nuovo" (masculine, singular), "Nuevos" (masculine, plural), "Nueva" (feminine, singular) "Nuevas" (feminine, plural)
- the same word can be translated differently if it has a different meaning.

  Example: "Scan" will have different translations if it is about scanning the disk (for a virus) or scanning a piece of paper.

So, you don't want to "magically merge strings" to save a few cents, if the price is lower translations quality.

Comment: Of course I don't want to do it entirely automatically. I'm asking for a tool to help me *identify* the above *possibly* similar strings so I can make an informed decision about them.